# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, size, sftp

i set in **wp-config** file `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` but still showing

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 77 bytes) in
>   /home/content/n3pnexwpnas03_data03/28/41282628/html/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/helpers/class-fw-cache.php
>   on line 262

i am using sftp server. so i cant change in defult-constant.php  how can i solver this error for wordpress?

Comment: what exactly are you doing? sound like you're trying to download a big file, I would suggest to try and download the file in smaller chunks.

Comment: As you say in a comment that you're on hosted sharing, you cannot change the memory limit yourself. You will need to contact your hosting provider and possibly have to upgrade or change hosting. What are you trying to do thats using so much memory?

Answer (score 1):

got a solution, i just added in wp-config.php file define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); define( 'WP_CACHE', 'true'); now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you should raise the memory limit in the php.ini file.

Comment: i added in php.ini  memory_limit = 256M ; but still same error

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards?

Comment: sir we are using shared hosting

Comment: sorry, that is not an answer to my question. i cannot help you if i need to make assumptions. I have experience with large memory issues.

Comment: sir, got a solution, i just added in wp-config.php file define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_CACHE', 'true');
now its working fine